# strange behavior in for loop - a bug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compiler-construction

I'm working with Visual Studio 2012 on a Windows 7 machine and when trying to run the following code snippet (compiled with the default VC11 C++ compiler in x64 mode) the assertion fails, which means, that the inner loop is never entered:

```
void loopTest1()
{
    const unsigned int k = 1;

    for (int m=0; m<3; ++m)
    {
        int acc = 0;

        for (int n=m-k; n<=m+k; ++n)
        {
            if (n<0 || n>=3) continue;

            ++acc;
        }

        assert (acc>0);

        cout << "acc: " << acc << endl;
    }
}
```

Now I change the inner loop's end condition:

```
void loopTest2()
{
    const unsigned int k = 1;

    for (int m=0; m<3; ++m)
    {
        int acc = 0;

        int l = m+k; // this line was added
        for (int n=m-k; n<=l; ++n) // m+k was replaced by l
        {
            if (n<0 || n>=3) continue;

            ++acc;
        }

        assert (acc>0);

        cout << "acc: " << acc << endl;
    }
}
```

Then I get the correct result:

```
acc: 2
acc: 3
acc: 2
```

When I replace the  `const unsigned int k` by a hard-coded 1, it works, too:

```
void loopTest3()
{
    //const unsigned int k = 1;

    for (int m=0; m<3; ++m)
    {
        int acc = 0;

        for (int n=m-1; n<=m+1; ++n) //replaced k with 1
        {
            if (n<0 || n>=3) continue;

            ++acc;
        }

        assert (acc>0);

        cout << "acc: " << acc << endl;
    }
}
```

Does the compiler perform some false optimizations?
Or is there any specific reason, why the behavior in the first case is at least unexpected?

Comment: You could try inspecting the disassembly to see the emitted code.

Comment: The compiler is probably raising a warning about a unsigned / signed mismatch because you subtract the unsigned int k from the signed int m - maybe fixing that already resolves the issue.

Comment: @Niko, It should, yes.

Comment: Niko, I just tested it with an `int k = 1` and it worked! Could you please turn repeat your comment in an answer?

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the function beginning and once it is hit call Debug->Windows->Disassembly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `int m` is going to be promoted to an `unsigned int`. On the first loop, that means `m-k` is equal to -1 as an unsigned value, which is the maximum unsigned value and obviously greater than `m+k` (when `n` is compared, it gets promoted). To put it in perspective, you'll end up with `n` being an unsigned representation of -1 and `m+k` being 1. Of course when you store that -1 unsigned into a signed integer, it overflows and is technically undefined behaviour. It's most likely keeping its -1 representation and then being promoted back to a max unsigned value.

Here's a summary of sorts of the first iteration:

> Iteration 1:
>   m: 0
>   k: 1u
>   n=m-k: -1u = max uint, stored into signed int
>   m+k: 1u
>   n<=m+k --> max uint <= 1u

In your second example, `n` is not promoted when compared to the other signed integer and it compares two signed integers. In your third, nothing is unsigned.

Comment: So I'd have to write `int n = m - static_cast<int>(k)` in the for loop, if I want to keep the k unsigned, right?

Comment: @Ben, That seems it would be the best option if you want to stick with number one, but you'll also need `n <= m + static_cast<int>(k)` so that `n` is not promoted to an unsigned integer there. You could also take number two and make a temporary `int` holding `m - static_cast<int>(k)` if you want to avoid the undefined behaviour and reduce the loop header size. The thing about signed overflows is that in nearly all cases, they will just wrap around and not cause any weird behaviour, so it's up to you if you want to stay away from it. Just keep in mind it's officially undefined.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that, too. Thanks for that great answer! I didn't see that problem at all, because I was expecting `k` to be promoted to an `int`.

Comment: @Ben, The promotions and standard arithmetic conversions in C++ can really bite hard if you don't anticipate them. STL actually had a video discussing a bug that arose in MSVC from them. It's video number 7 in his Core C++ series.